.NET 8 Isolated Azure Function throws a socket and SQL timeout exception
We are migrating our application from .NET 6 to .NET 8 isolated. All integration tests pass locally. But while deploying to the dev environment, when the integration tests run, a few tests are failing due to SQL timeouts.
We have added functionTimeout in host.json, but they still fail. We have upgraded all the nuget packages. Am I missing anything? Thanks in advance.
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:30:00"
}

Function
[Function("ApplicationApp")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ApplicationApp(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "put", Route = "application")]
        HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpRequestData httpRequestData, ILogger logger, CancellationToken token)
{
    // ...
}

Error
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): The wait operation timed out.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteReaderAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
ClientConnectionId:31d3e43d-1530-4b8e-bda6-9adce6679f20
Error Number:-2,State:0,Class:11


Please share the error which you are getting.

@Harshitha Error details updated above.

@Mukesh, Are you still facing the issue? Check if below solution helps

The error occurring could be due to either network or resource constraints.
Ensure that valid SQL connection string is added in the App Settings of Azure function app.
Increase the connection Timeout in the connection string as below:
Server=tcp:<servername>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<dbname>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={UserID};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=300;

Check the Application logs in Invocations under function app to figure out the root cause for the error.

I have created a .NET 8.0 isolated Azure function for SQL Trigger Output binding.
 public class Function1
 {
     private readonly ILogger _logger;

     public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
     {
         _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
     }

     // Visit https://aka.ms/sqlbindingsoutput to learn how to use this output binding
     [Function("Function1")]
     [SqlOutput("[dbo].[table2]", "demo")]
     public async Task<ToDoItem> Run(
         [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestData req)
     {
         _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger with SQL Output Binding function processed a request.");

         ToDoItem todoitem = await req.ReadFromJsonAsync<ToDoItem>() ?? new ToDoItem
             {
                 Id = <id>,
                 Name = "<name>",
                 Age = <age>,
                 Email = "abc@gmail.com"
             };
         return todoitem;
     }
 }

 public class ToDoItem
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Age { get; set; }
     public string Email { get; set; }
 }

local response:


Able to run the function as expected:


Response:

Connected! You are now viewing logs of Function runs in the current Code + Test panel. To see all the logs for this Function, please go to 'Logs' from the Function menu.
2024-10-16T14:37:47Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=e3cbba55-8d33-4131-a7ab-7b1f74e9e409)
2024-10-16T14:37:47Z   [Information]   C# HTTP trigger with SQL Output Binding function processed a request.
2024-10-16T14:37:51Z   [Information]   Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=e3cbba55-8d33-4131-a7ab-7b1f74e9e409, Duration=3925ms)

Database Response:

